# Proof for arithmetic progression with different indices

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

How do I show that $\left(a_n\right)_{n\geq1}$ is an arithmetic progression if and only if $a_i+a_j-a_k = a_{\left(i+j-k\right)}$.

I tried by using the different definitions for arithmetic progressions and equating them, but I have no clue how to solve this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is an AP. Then $a_n = a_1 + (n - 1)d$ for some $d$, so:
\begin{align*}
a_i + a_j - a_k &= (a_1 + (i - 1)d) + (a_1 + (j - 1)d) - (a_1 + (k - 1)d) \\
&= a_1 + (i + j - k - 1)d \\
&= a_{i+j-k}
\end{align*}
Now suppose $a_i + a_j - a_k = a_{i+j-k} \; \forall i,j,k \geq 1$. Then:
$$
a_{i} + a_{i+2} - a_{i+1} = a_{i + (i+2) - (i+1)} = a_{i+1} \implies a_{i+2} - a_{i+1} = a_{i+1} - a_i
$$
Thus, $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is an AP.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed the first part, but really struggled with the second. Your reply provided the answer

Answer (score 0):

Given $a_i + a_j - a_k = a_{(i+j-k)}$:
So, $a_i - a_k = a_{(i+j-k)} - a_j$
Take $i-k=d$
Then 
$a_{k+d} - a_k = a_{j+d} - a_j$.  Therefore it is A.P.

Other way round is even easier. 
You can try.